# ogr2gr loading spatial data into mysql

Tags: ogr2ogr, mysql

I am trying to load shapefile into mysql (MYISAM) using ogr2ogr and i get an error that says failed to fetch the requested layer. What could be wrong with my statement is it the issue with quotes or not quotes. using ogr2ogr to check the validity of the shapefile produces results. I am working in a windows environment.
  ogr2ogr --config SHAPE_ENCODING="UTF-8" -f "MySql" MySql:"database_name,
    host=127.0.0.1,user=myUser,password=myPass,port=3306"
-lco engine=MYISAM "C:\data\county.shp"
-nln county -nlt "Multilinestring" -s_srs EPSG:4326

Comment: check your shapefile if exist the file with cpg extension. XXX.cpg

Comment: Consider to add this as a comment.